# Equality of dimension of global sections of two sheaves on a $K3$ surface

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let, $E$ be a locally free sheaf on a $K3$ surface which is globally generated away from a finite set of points.Let's denote $S_E$ to be the cokernel of the evaluation map $ H^0(E) \otimes \mathcal O_X \to E$ and also let's denote $R_E := \mathcal{E}xt^2(S_E, \mathcal O_X)$.[Here we work under the assumption $H^0(E^*) =0$]

Then my question is :Is it true that $H^0(R_E) = H^1(E^*)$?(Or may be they have same dimension as a vector space?)

Attempt:From the  exact sequence $ 0\to E^* \to (H^0(E))^* \otimes \mathcal O_X \to V^* \to R_E$,(where $V$ =kernel of the above mentioned evaluation map) if we try to construct a short exact sequence of the form 
$ 0 \to E^* \to F \to R_E \to 0$, with $H^i(F) =0$ for $i=0,1$, then I think we have the desired equality.But I don't see How  we can have such a short exact sequence.

I also tried to compute dimension of vector spaces from the short exact sequences that come out of the given exact sequence, there also I don't see any equality .

Any help from anyone is welcome.

Comment: Do you mean $\mathcal{Ext}^1$?

Comment: @hunter, we have $R_E = \mathcal{E}xt^2(S_E, \mathcal O_X) =   \mathcal{E}xt^1(Imf, \mathcal O_X)$ where $f$ is the evaluation map

Comment: Hmm, then should the $E^*$ in the exact sequence of paragraph three be $(\text{Im} f)^*$?

Comment: @hunter,yes they are isomorphic